# Unable to Iterate Integer in list using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to build a code which automatically fill the text field in textbox,These codes are working as string in list but cant able to iterate integer .

I have tried to do  many steps but this is not working ,however code is working in python .

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("pwd")
elem.send_keys("oyo@1234")
time.sleep(2)
elem = browser.find_element_by_name('Submit').click()
elem = browser.find_element_by_name('login_existing_agent').click()
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/img").click()
#browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/ul[2]/li[3]/a").click()
time.sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/ul[2]/li[3]/a").click()

agent_id = [4600000 ,4600001 , 4600002]
a = len(agent_id)

agent_name = [ "saurav" ,"nishant", "vikash"]
b = len(agent_name)

sip_pass = ["Oyo4600000" ,"Oyo4600001" , "Oyo4600002"]
c = len(sip_pass)


i = 0
j  =0 
k =0
while ( i< a  and j<b and k<c ) :

    elem = browser.find_element_by_name('agent_add_ui').click()
    elem = browser.find_element_by_name('agent_secret')
    elem.send_keys("123456")
    dropdown = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='campaign_id']")
    select =Select(dropdown)
    select.select_by_visible_text('GOOGLE')

    elem = browser.find_element_by_name('agent_id')
    elem.send_keys(agent_id[i])

    elem = browser.find_element_by_name('agent_name')
    elem.send_keys(agent_name[j])


    elem = browser.find_element_by_name('sip_pass')
    elem.send_keys(sip_pass[k])
    elem = browser.find_element_by_name('add_agent').click()

    i += 1
    j += 1
    k += 1


browser.close()
```

Comment: Which steps _...is not working..._ exactly?

Comment: Thanks but its resolved ,as the maimum digit of  id is five ,i am sending six digit thats why it  only place same value again and agian ,thanks .

Comment: I have one more question is there any way we can create credenials using APi Directly

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to first convert each item in your list of integers, into a string, before specifying the item via its index within 'send_keys', not to worry, str() will do the trick :)

```
elem.send_keys(str(agent_id[i]))
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this also but isssue resolved as maximum digit of creating id is 5 digits thats why its sending only same value

Comment: @user8100805 If I was at all helpful, a thumbs up when you get a chance :)